# Fetch the body of a request on chrome and use it on a postman request

Tags: python, google-chrome, postman

I'm trying to fetch the JSON reply for a request originated in a python script:

```python
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

... and send it as the body in Postman request to a different API.

There are several iterations on the script. I was able to open 50 Tabs in Chrome with it but now how do I automate the copy-paste body process to Postman.

Answer (score 2):

**There's not really a supported way to communicate with the Postman app from a different process to run requests** (see e.g. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/86), it falls out of the scope of the tool.

If I understood well the gist of the question; basically, what you're trying to achieve is to concatenate a couple of network requests, reusing data between them. As I see it, there's a couple of approaches you can take:

### Do both requests on your python code:

You don't need the overhead of opening a browser to send a HTTP request; instead, simply use a library - like [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) - to do the job. Here's an example:

```py
import req
# First request is a GET to "url"
r1 = requests.get(url)
# POST the contents of r1's reply to a different endpoint:
r2 = requests.post("http://url.tld/endpoint", data=r1.json())
```

From there you can continue querying `r2` in the script to find out details or manipulate the data.

### Create 2 different Postman requests and run them in sequence

Similarly, you can create both requests in postman, use the [test](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts) tab to extract the body of the response, save it as environment variable and then reuse it on next requests.

```js
var body = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("body", body);
```

You can access the env.var. with the handlebars notation - i.e. `{{body}}`

Note that if there was any extra reason you wanted to do the request from the browser (e.g. cookies) you can manually export one as cURL from the [Network tab on the Chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy) and [import it back to postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/data_formats#importing-curl) or capture the browser's activity using [Postman interceptor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests). This will preserve headers/any additional data to be able to reuse it in the future.